# Diophantine equation $3(a^4+a^2b^2+b^4)+(c^4+c^2d^2+d^4)=3(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am looking for positive integer solutions to the Diophantine equation $3(a^4+a^2b^2+b^4)+(c^4+c^2d^2+d^4)=3(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$ for distinct values of $(a,b,c,d)$.

There are many solutions with $a=b$ such as $(7,7,11,13)$ and $(13,13,22,23)$, and many solutions with $c=d$ such as $(3,5,7,7)$ and $(7,8,13,13)$, but it seems not so many with $4$ distinct values.  The smallest distinct solution I know of is $(35,139,146,169)$.

Are there infinitely many solutions?  Is there perhaps a parameterization of such solutions?

Of special interest are solutions where the quantity $(c^2+d^2)-(a^2+b^2)$ is a perfect square, such as $(a,b,c,d)=(323,392,407,713)$.  Are there other solutions of this type?

This comes up in solving an unsolved problem in geometry that I can't discuss, but you might get your name on a paper if you can help.

Answer (score 16):

The equation you specify defines a surface $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$, and this surface is a K3 surface. It is conjectured that if $X$ is a K3 surface, there is a field extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ over which the rational points on $X$ become Zariski dense. It's not clear that this happens over $\mathbb{Q}$.

However, one can find infinitely many solutions by finding genus $0$ curves on this surface. Specializing the polynomial to make $c = a+b$ it becomes the square of a quadratic, and this quadratic (which defines a conic in $\mathbb{P}^{2}$) has infinitely many points.

In particular, if $s$ and $t$ are positive integers with $s > t$, then
$a = s^{2}-t^{2}$, $b = 2st - t^{2}$, $c = s^{2} + 2st - 2t^{2}$, $d = s^{2} - st + t^{2}$ is a solution in positive integers to your equation. (The only solution in this family with $c^2+d^{2}-a^{2}-b^{2}$ a square is $a = c = d = 3$, $b = 0$. However, there easily could have been more.)

EDIT: The rational points on $X$ are Zariski dense. If $w$ is a rational number, specializing the polynomial at $c = aw + b$ gives a genus $1$ curve. This curve has a section, and using this, the surface $X$ is birational to the elliptic surface
$$
  E : y^{2} = x^{3} + (6w^{4} - 30w^{2} + 24)x^{2} + (9w^{8} - 90w^{6} + 189w^{4} - 144w^{2} + 36)x.
$$
It's not too hard to find two independent points of infinite order on this elliptic surface, and the preimage on $X$ of a point on $E/\mathbb{Q}(w)$ is a rational curve. In particular $X$ has infinitely many rational curves.

One of the simplest rational curves gives rise to solutions with $a < b < c < d$. In particular, let $w = \frac{s}{t}$ with $s$ and $t$ coprime positive integers and $\frac{1}{2} < \frac{s}{t} < \frac{-1 + \sqrt{13}}{4}$. Then
\begin{align*}
  a &= 32s^{5} t - 56s^{3} t^{3} + 8s^{2}t^{4} + 30st^{5} - 11t^{6}\\
  b &= -16s^{6} - 16s^{5} t + 28s^{4} t^{2} + 48s^{3} t^{3} - 31s^{2} t^{4} - 32 st^{5} + 19t^{6}\\
  c &= 16s^{6} - 16s^{5} t - 28s^{4} t^{2} + 56s^{3} t^{3} - s^{2} t^{4} - 43st^{5} + 19t^{6}\\
  d &= -16 s^{6} - 32s^{5} t + 52s^{4} t^{2} + 40s^{3} t^{3} - 47 s^{2} t^{4} - 14st^{5} + 14t^{6}
\end{align*}
is a solution with $0 < a < b < c < d$ and with $c = (s/t)a + b$. For example setting $s = 5$ and $t = 8$, each of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ above are multiples of $48$ and dividing through by that gives $(1392,2197,3067,3197)$.

Comment: Yes, there was a typo. The correct equation for $c$ is $c = s^{2}+2st-2t^{2}$.

Comment: This quartic surface $X$ has 16 nodes, and is thus not just a K3 surface but
a Kummer surface; if I did this right, it's the Kummer of
the Jacobian of the curve $y^2 = (x-2) x (2x-1) (x^2-4x+1)$,
which is isogenous to the product of two elliptic curves of the same
$j$-invariant $35152/9$.  So, as often happens with K3's arising from
geometrical configurations, our $X$ has near-maximal Picard number, here $19$.
Even with some of the curves on $X$ not defined over $\bf Q$,
there should still be enough to prove the rational points are Zariski-dense.

Comment: However, it seems that adding the condition $(c^2+d^2)-(a^2+b^2) = \Box$
gives a surface of general type, so one expects (Bombieri-Lang conjectures) 
that all the rational points are accounted for by finitely many 
rational curves, elliptic curves, and sporadic points -- 
but we do not usually know how to prove that for any given surface,
nor even (with very few exceptions, which don't include the present surface)
how to be sure that we have
a complete list of rational or elliptic curves on the surface.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies I think those remarks deserve to be put in an answer of their own.

Comment: What I really need are solutions with $a < b < c < d$.  So assumptions like $c=a+b$ or $c=b+d$ don't help me much.

Comment: My answer has been updated to include a parametrization with solutions satisfying your condition that $a < b < c < d$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies From what you write it seems to follow (if I am not mistaken) that the K3 surface obtained from resolving the singularities of $X$ is isogenous (in the sense of an isogeny of K3s) to the Kummer of a product $E \times E'$, where $E,E'$ are elliptic curves that are quadratic twists of each other. Is that correct? And do you also happen to know whether $E'$ is actually a *non-trivial* twist of $E$? Because in the special case of Kummers of $E \times E$, for those it is particularly easy to prove (Zariski) density of rational points, and often density in much finer topologies.

Comment: [Just to prove the last assertion, even though it might be irrelevant in case $E$ and $E'$ are non-isomorphic: the surface $\operatorname{Kum}(E \times E)$ receives dominant rational maps from $E^\tau \times E^\tau$ where $E^\tau$ ranges over the quadratic twists of $E$. It is pretty easy to construct a $\tau$ for which $E^\tau$ has positive rank. In that case, not only do the rational points in the image of $E^\tau \times E^\tau \dashrightarrow \operatorname{Kum}(E \times E)$ lie Zariski-dense, they even lie dense in a non-empty open subset of the $p$-adic points, for all $p$.]

Answer (score 3):

$3(a^4+a^2b^2+b^4)+(c^4+c^2d^2+d^4)=3(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)\tag{1}$

We show above equation gives infinitely many integer solutions if c = b+d.

We get
$$a^2 = \frac{c^2+d^2-b^2}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{-3c^4+6c^2d^2+18b^2c^2-3d^4+18b^2d^2-27b^4}}{6}\tag{2}$$

Hence we find the rational solutions of quartic curve for $c$ below $$v^2 = -3c^4+(18b^2+6d^2)c^2+18b^2d^2-27b^4-3d^4\tag{3}$$

Let $c = b+d$, then RHS of equation $(3)$ becomes to $-12b^2(b^2-2bd-2d^2)$.

Parametric solution of $b^2-2bd-2d^2=-3u^2$ is given
$(b,d)= \left( \dfrac{-5-2k+k^2}{(k+2)(k-1)}, \dfrac{2(1+k+k^2)}{(k+2)(k-1)} \right)$.

Hence equation $(3)$ has a solution $(c,v)= \left( \dfrac{7+4k+k^2}{(k+2)(k-1)}, \dfrac{6(k^2+4k+1)(-5-2k+k^2)}{(k+2)^2(k-1)^2} \right)$.

k is arbitrary.

Then we get $a^2 = \dfrac{3(k^4+4k^3+4k^2+3)}{(k+2)^2(k-1)^2}$.

Hence we find the rational solutions of quartic curve

$$V^2 = 3(k^4+4k^3+4k^2+3)\tag{4}$$
Quartic curve $(4)$ can be transformed to elliptic curve below.

$Y^2 = X^3 -156X + 560$ with rank 1 and generator is $P(X,Y)=(2,-16)$.

Hence this cuve has infinitely many rational points.

One of rational points is $2P(X,Y)=(\frac{65}{4}, \frac{-385}{8})$.

This point gives a solution $(a,b,c,d)=(1407459, 656995, 1391911, 2048906)$.

Thus equation $(1)$ gives infinitely many integer solutions.

Another solution of equation $(1)$ with $c\neq a\pm b, d\neq a\pm b$.

$a = 7n^4+100n^3+42n^2+100n+7$
$b = 13n^4+28n^3+174n^2+28n+13$
$c = 19n^4+112n^3+174n^2-56n+7$
$d = 7n^4-56n^3+174n^2+112n+19$
$n$ is arbitrary.
$n = 5$ is excluded.

```
             n     a      b      c       d
            [2    143    133    199     67]
            [3    247    217    373     61]
            [4   9271   8029  14599   1459]
            [6  32791  29341  54751   3931]
            [7   3367   3097   5761    433]
            [8   9263   8773  16207   1339]
            [9    481    469    859     79]
            [10 175207 175693 318847  32539]
```

Numerical solutions of equation $(1)$.
$(a,b,c,d)<1000$
fg1: 1 ($c=a\pm b,d=a\pm b$)
fg2: s ($c^2+d^2-a^2-b^2$ is square number)

There are many solutions such as $c\neq a\pm b, d\neq a\pm b$.
Total number of solutions : $378$
Case of $c=a\pm b,d=a\pm b: 274(72.5$ percecnt)
Others: $104(27.5$ percent)

There are two solutions such as $c^2+d^2-a^2-b^2$ is square number.
$(a,b,c,d)=(645, 323, 713, 407),(645, 392, 713, 407)$
There is no other solution with $(a,b,c,d)<10000$

```
                a     b     c     d fg1 fg2
                5     3     7     2 1   
                8     7    13     1 1   
               16     5    19    11 1   
               24    11    31    13 1   
               31    24    43    11     
               33     7    37    26 1   
               35    13    43    22 1   
               39    16    49    23 1   
               43    35    62    13     
               45    32    67    13 1   
               49    39    74    11     
               51    40    79    11 1   
               56    39    67    31     
               56     9    61    47 1   
               57    35    77    23     
               57    55    97     2 1   
               63    17    73    46 1   
               77    40   103    37 1   
               80    19    91    61 1   
               85    11    91    74 1   
               88    65   133    23 1   
               91    69   139    22 1   
               95    24   109    71 1   
               97    73   122    49     
              105   104   181     1 1   
              112    75   163    37 1   
              115    56   151    59 1   
              120    13   127   107 1   
              120    23   133    97 1   
              143   133   199    67     
              143    25   157   118 1   
              145   119   229    26 1   
              152    65   163   103     
              152    35   143   133     
              152   147   247    23     
              152    35   143   133     
              155    87   193    77     
              155   144   259    11 1   
              160    87   217    73 1   
              161    15   169   146 1   
              161   151   266    13     
              165    56   199   109 1   
              168    85   223    83 1   
              169    31   161   151     
              175    32   193   143 1   
              187    93   247    94 1   
              192   133   283    59 1   
              195    29   211   166 1   
              203    72   247   131 1   
              205   163   247   122     
              208    17   217   191 1   
              209   136   301    73 1   
              217    95   277   122 1   
              221    64   259   157 1   
              224    31   241   193 1   
              231   185   361    46 1   
              240   229   341   109     
              247   105   313   142 1   
              247   168   271   163     
              247   217   373    61     
              253   240   427    13 1   
              259   176   379    83 1   
              261    19   271   242 1   
              272   105   337   167 1   
              273   152   373   121 1   
              279    40   301   239 1   
              280   111   349   169 1   
              280   133   337   157     
              280   201   259   241     
              287   240   457    47 1   
              288    35   307   253 1   
              291   115   314   199     
              299   205   439    94 1   
              301   275   499    26 1   
              304   161   409   143 1   
              315    88   367   227 1   
              320    21   331   299 1   
              323    37   343   286 1   
              325   193   407   157     
              325   264   511    61 1   
              333   115   403   218 1   
              336   215   481   121 1   
              343   255   473   122     
              344   305   539    59     
              351   329   589    22 1   
              352   123   427   229 1   
              357    80   403   277 1   
              368   297   577    71 1   
              368   335   473   217     
              369   175   481   194 1   
              385    23   397   362 1   
              387   208   523   179 1   
              391   129   469   262 1   
              399    41   421   358 1   
              400   377   673    23 1   
              407    48   433   359 1   
              416   235   571   181 1   
              423   280   613   143 1   
              424   395   559   241     
              425   184   541   241 1   
              433   217   559   218     
              437    88   487   349 1   
              440    43   463   397 1   
              440   189   559   251 1   
              441   319   661   122 1   
              451   104   511   347 1   
              456    25   469   431 1   
              459   245   619   214 1   
              473   135   553   338 1   
              475   141   559   334 1   
              477   403   763    74 1   
              480   371   739   109 1   
              493   312   703   181 1   
              495   448   817    47 1   
              504   409   581   337     
              513   200   637   313 1   
              517   203   643   314 1   
              520   341   751   179 1   
              520   147   607   373 1   
              527   385   793   142 1   
              528    47   553   481 1   
              533    27   547   506 1   
              536   465   781   169     
              539   240   691   299 1   
              544   531   931    13 1   
              545   441   806   139     
              551   265   721   286 1   
              552   145   637   407 1   
              559    56   589   503 1   
              559   240   671   329     
              560   429   859   131 1   
              561   464   889    97 1   
              575    49   601   526 1   
              583   320   793   263 1   
              589   336   811   253 1   
              589   555   946    91     
              595   549   991    46 1   
              600   217   733   383 1   
              611   120   679   491 1   
              613   245   598   473     
              616    29   631   587 1   
              616   159   709   457 1   
              616   559   889   229     
              621   104   679   517 1   
              624   325   851   301     
              627   413   907   214 1   
              637   155   727   482 1   
              645   323   713   407    s
              645   392   713   407    s
              649   455   961   194 1   
              665   336   671   481     
              665   193   767   473     
              667   165   763   502 1   
              675    53   703   622 1   
              679   151   722   539     
              680   427   967   253 1   
              689   231   829   458 1   
              695   488   817   403     
              696   385   949   311 1   
              704   295   889   409 1   
              705    31   721   674 1   
              713   232   853   481 1   
              715   272   883   443 1   
              721   344   923   379     
              725   112   787   613 1   
              728    55   757   673 1   
              728   165   823   563 1   
              728   703   937   469     
              735    64   769   671 1   
              744   169   869   581     
              759   305   949   454 1   
              767   360   997   407 1   
              775   177   877   598 1   
              776   489   869   481     
              795   136   871   659 1   
              800    33   817   767 1   
              805   189   869   626     
              825   248   973   577 1   
              832   183   937   649 1   
              840    59   871   781 1   
              845   328   763   713     
              883   480   893   637     
              899    61   931   838 1   
              901    35   919   866 1   
              907   155   938   767     
              912   427   973   613     
              921    91   913   851     
              935    72   973   863 1   
              936   775   989   739
```